# Infinite data for scp

Tags: scp

I am trying to have an infinite scp between two hosts but of course there is no such file large enough for this.

I tried

> `scp -l 512 192.168.1.1:/dev/zero /dev/null`

But scp says /dev/zero not a regular file.

I need a consistent traffic between two hosts so I can try something on my router/firewall and I really need it to run for a long time.

Any suggestions? It does not have to be scp but I need to be able to specify the speed.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `scp` tool expects to copy a file. You can use `ssh` to transport an unending stream of bytes, and you can rate-limit with something like `pv`. The pertinent section of the man page for `pv` writes,

> **`-L RATE`, `--rate-limit RATE`** Limit the transfer to a maximum of RATE bytes per second. A suffix of `K`, `M`,  `G`,  or  `T` can be added to denote Kilobytes (*1024), Megabytes, and so on.

A suitable solution would be something like this, which rate-limits at approximately 10Mb/s (remember that 1MB/s is approximately 10Mb/s, after accounting for padding, network headers, etc.):

```
pv --rate-limit 1M </dev/zero | ssh user@example.net 'cat >/dev/null'
```

If you want bidirectional traffic flow, remove the quotes from the `'cat >/dev/null'`.

Comment: +1. you can also do this with `scp` itself if you use a modernish shell (e.g. bash, ksh, zsh. not ash or dash) that supports process substitution.  `scp <(pv ...) user@example.net:/dev/null`

Comment: I tried this on CentOS 7 scp still compliants about not a regular file.

Comment: so it does...I should have tested that before commenting.  maybe there is some valid reason for `scp` to care whether a file is a regular file or not. or maybe it's just some over-zealous special-case handling.  dunno.

Comment: @cas it introduces ambiguity, so it's blocked. Consider `scp /dev/sdc3 remote:/dev/sdc3` where the destination does not exist. Should this copy the device node? What about its contents? Since `sdc3` is missing on the target should we copy the contents to a _file_ on the destination?

Comment: @roaima i don't see any ambiguity, everything is a file (or close enough to a file), and i'd say yes - that command *should* result in the contents of /dev/sdc3 being copied to a file.  warning a user of the consequences may, in some circumstances, be acceptable.  arbitrarily preventing them from doing something that their user account is authorised to do is not and never will be.   `cat /dev/sdc3 | ssh remote 'cat > /dev/sdc3'` can work if perms etc allow.  scp should work too.

Comment: @cas https://serverfault.com/questions/27397/sync-lvm-snapshots-to-backup-server/168034#168034 and an explanation at http://strugglers.net/~andy/blog/2011/03/13/copying-block-devices-between-machines/

Comment: @cas ah, original source. Look who's the author :-) https://lists.samba.org/archive/rsync/2010-June/025164.html

Comment: rsync is different to ssh or scp.   BTW, for live-migrating VMs, I `zfs send` the VM's ZVOL to my secondary VM host :), and that's usually **very** quick because it's only a small update since the most recent snapshot send.  The DRBD idea in the strugglers.net article is nicely implemented in google's [ganeti](http://www.ganeti.org/). I've got ganeti working with ZFS at home, but I don't really need ganeti here.  libvirt plus my own scripts suffice.  $workplaces that have paid me to do VM stuff tend to go for vmware, xen, openstack, or containers with docker. I quite like the latter 3.

Answer (score 0):

from [commandlinefu.com](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/5799/test-network-speed-without-wasting-disk):
<s>`dd if=/dev/zero bs=4096 count=1048576 | ssh user@host.tld 'cat > /dev/null'`</s>

As a helpful user posted, this will stop at 4GiB, which is not infinite.  Therefore:

`</dev/zero ssh user@host.tld 'cat > /dev/null'`

Comment: 4GB is not infinite. Why make this complicated? `</dev/zero ssh user@host.tld 'cat > /dev/null'`